# SharePoint Online Image library with metadata collumns

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, metadata, picture-library

[image][image]I am experiencing an issue with metadata.
I have an Image Library that has around 8000 files. I had uploaded them with metadata for some custom collumns.

I did create a few views filtering with that collumns informations.

The problem is that when I click in filter button, SharePoint Online shows my filter collumns out of sort.
For example... I have pictures, and a collumns called Original Date: 1910, 1905, 1923, 1911, etc.

How can SharePoint Online shows these collumns in alphabetical order?

All our columns are plain text of a line as you can see in the photo when clicking no button filter it does not group in alphabetical order

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the column that is not appearing as sorted in filter? Is it a single line of text column?

Comment: All our columns are plain text of a line as you can see in the photo when clicking no button filter it does not group in alphabetical order

Thanks Denilson

Comment: please check my answer to troubleshoot your o365.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the filter pane displays the single line of text data in the descending order. I changed the values, refreshed the page and filter pane sorted the values in descending order.

[image]

Try two things to make it work on your o365.

1. Unpin the other filters and refresh the page.
2. Change the language to English. This is to make sure its not a language issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I use a single line of text column to store these value, when I filter the column using the column filter, it show the values in alphabetical order:
[image]

So, for this issue, please use Single Line of text column to store the values.

Comment: All our columns are plain text of a line as you can see in the photo when clicking no button filter it does not group in alphabetical order

Thanks Denilson

Comment: You need to use Single Line of Text column

Comment: Hi guys! Just to up to date. The Filter Button doesnt sort by Alphabetical order. It does by RELEVANCE. I did confirm with Microsoft Support. They give me a site to send my suggestion, because I should be able to change this for Alphabetical.

Comment: Kally or anyone ... is there a way to fix the "ARRANGE" option enabled by default? I will need to use that option, and our users are very dummies. It would be great if they enter and see that option already clicked. They will use the FILTER and SORT of the collumns. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear... you can see the ARRANGE option (or ORGANIZE in some systems), when you change to THUMBNAIL (or TILE) view. You will see the ARRANGE. When you click it, The collumns names appears, and it is possible to right-click on each collumn to apply filters.